# I cant install plugins in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I wanted to install a plugin in Android Studio, so I went to "settings ->plugins -> browse repositories", then I selected the plugin I wanted and clicked the install button ([Pitcure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KOs4.png)), but after I 'installed' the plugin,  Android Studio needed to restart to complete the installation([Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fge7s.png)). When AS restarted, the plugin was not installed.

Answer (score 4):

After many tries I found a solution:

1. I realised, I changed some folder paths in AS, because I have one SSD disk with low storage and all the folders were installed in that disk. I changed most of those folder paths to [another disk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCgNY.png) with more capacity.
2. Then I found out, the plugins I tried to install, were downloaded in the [".AndroidStudio3.1\system\plugins"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXsAw.png) folder.
3. I moved the plugin file that I wanted to install to the  plugins folder where AS Is installed ["D:\ProgramFiles\Android\Android Studio\plugins"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5G67d.png).
4. Finally, I went to AS and installed de plugin from disk ["settings ->plugins -> install plugin from disk"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1Pc7.png), I selected the plugin file located in [the step 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5G67d.png) and clicked in OK button. After AS restarted, the plugin was installed.

Comment: I have tried "Install plugin from dist", but it didn't work. Instead I just copied the files from downloaded .zip to AndroidStudio/plugins folder and that's it! (I have renamed the copied folder in order to eliminate spaced in it)

Comment: It works for me too, but this is just a workaround. The problem is not solved. I was looking for a long term solution.